# how to Integrating Font Face in Android WebView Text without Using Scripts

Tags: android, webview, font-family

Numerous solutions exist for adding font faces to text in Android WebView, typically involving HTML scripting and loading.

However, I'm seeking a method that involves direct settings changes within the WebView, bypassing the need for scripting.